# findByIdAndUpdate pull from array objects equal to a specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to remove one or more objects of type `tweet` from the `timeline` list within the user model. The `tweet` objects that I want to remove are those whose author id matches a specific id `user._id`.

I have tried this:

```
router.get("/follow/:userId", isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id).populate("timeline")
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId).populate("followers tweets")
        for (let tweet of currentUser.timeline) {
            if (tweet.author._id.equals(user._id)) {
                currentUser.timeline.pull(tweet._id)
            }
        }
        req.flash("error", `Unfollowed to ${user.username}`)
        user.save();
        currentUser.save()
        res.redirect(`/${user._id}`)
    } catch (err) {
        req.flash("error", err.message);
        res.redirect("back")
    }
}));
```

and this:

```
await User.findbyIdAndUpdate(currentuser._id, { $pull: { timeline: { author : user._id } } }
```

but none of them are working.

My user model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    biography: { type: String, maxlength: 160 },
    location: {type: String, maxlength: 30 },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        url: String,
        filename: String,
    },
    followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    tweets: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tweet"}],
    timeline: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tweet"}]
});
```

My tweet model :

```
const tweetSchema = new Schema({
    images: [{ 
        url: String,
        filename : String
    }],
    text: { type: String, maxlength: 260},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tweet", default:null },
    replies: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tweet" }],
    likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    retweets: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tweet" }],
    retweetStatus: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tweet", default: null}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your collection looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5707"),
    "name" : "Mary",
    "timeline" : [
      ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5703"),
      ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5704"),
      ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5705")
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5706"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth",
    "timeline" : [
      ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5700"),
      ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5701"),
      ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5702")
    ]
  }
]
```

then the solution is:

```js
usersSchema.updateOne(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5706"),
        "timeline": ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5700"),
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            "timeline": ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5700")
        }
    }
)
.then()
.catch()

// or

usersSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5706"),
        "timeline": ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5700"),
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            "timeline": ObjectId("60254276259a60228cbe5700")
        }
    },
    {
        new: true
    }
)
.then()
.catch()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried both in mongo but it doesnt work. But I need to make it work in my route with nodejs, not in mongo. Thanks

Comment: If the schema of the collection in my answer is correctly matching yours then those queries are correct. Its working for me at least.

Comment: I only have one suggestion then based on the typos in your question. Please check your code for typos in field names used in the query.

Comment: But in my user Schema collection, timeline is an array of objects Id:

`"timeline" : [
                ObjectId("6026883fac4a220fcf85309c"),
                ObjectId("6026883fac4a220fcf85309c"),]`

This is how it apears in Mongo. In my route i populate timeline to work with it.

Comment: If you use findOneAndUpdate then its important to pass "new" option with "true" value. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I've checked your answer but what I'm trying to achieve is to remove all the tweets written by a certain author. I'm trying to imitate Twitter when user A unfollows some user B, and therefore user A's timeline will update and stop showing user B's tweets. Could you check my updated answer? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have solved my issue. Thanks for your time! @Dheemanth

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue! The problem I was having is that I was trying to remove items from a list of objects while looping through that list. The solution is easy: you can just create an auxiliar empty array and push the items that you want to remove, then loop through that auxiliar array and pull the items from the original array.

In my case, I've already had an array with the tweets that I wanted to remove, `user.tweets`. The solution is:

```
router.get("/follow/:userId", isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id).populate("timeline")
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId).populate("followers tweets")
        for (let tweet of user.tweets) {
            currentUser.timeline.pull(tweet._id)
        }
        req.flash("error", `Unfollowed to ${user.username}`)
        user.save();
        currentUser.save()
        res.redirect(`/${user._id}`)
    } catch (err) {
        req.flash("error", err.message);
        res.redirect("back")
    }
}));
```